# JAAS Realm load internal config file

Tags: java, tomcat, jaas

I have implement a simple JAAS module with realm configuration on Tomcat 7. It works properly when specifying the jaas.conf file in the catalina.sh like so

```
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS "-Djava.security.auth.login.config==$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jaas.config"
```

However, I wanted to simplify my application by adding this config file internally to the web application. Documentation states that you can use the configFile param

"The name of a JAAS configuration file to use with this Realm. It will be searched for using ClassLoader#getResource(String) so it is possible for the configuration to be bundled within a web application. If not specified, the default JVM global JAAS configuration will be used."

My context.xml in my web app:

```
<Realm appName="AppLogin" className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" configFile="WEB-INF/jaas.config" ...../>
```

The config file is located /WEB-INF/jaas.config

Why is my jaas config file not being loaded?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/realm.html#JAAS_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It will be searched for using `ClassLoader#getResource(String)`

Then you need to put JAAS configuration file in the classpath: `WEB-INF/classes` or `WEB-INF/lib` but not `WEB-INF` directly.

And specify only the file name as it is written in the documentation:

> `configFile` - The name of a JAAS configuration file to use with this
>   Realm.

Comment: To clarify, I would put my files in the /resources/lib or /resources/classes folder for this to work. You answer lead me to make the proper conclusion.

Comment: @Sixthpoint - I am not aware that Tomcat has resources folder. What is full path of resources/classes? Relative to Tomcat installation or relative to web context?

Comment: not tomcat specific, placed it in the same directory as java, and webapps. So this would be in /src/main/resources

Comment: Works for me, my path is src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jaas.conf and i reference it using confileFile="jaas.conf".

Answer (score 0):

It appears that configFile attribute is not implemented in Tomcat 7 even though the documentation states that it is. I examined the source for org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm and there is no method for setConfigFile.

When you use a attribute that has no associated method implemented, Tomcat reports a message like the following:

> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Realm} Setting property
>   'configFile' to 'jaas.config' did not find a matching property.

That message indicates that **configFile** attribute is not recognized and therefore JAASRealm will not know where to look for jaas.config.

So it appears that for Tomcat 7, you can only specify jaas.config with -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jaas.config

Tomcat 8 source has method for setConfigFile in org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm. I have not tried Tomcat 8.